Apache Superset modal editor not fully shown
When opening the modal editor, there's a scrollbar despite having enough space to display all the content.
Example: there are 20 lines of code here, but I have to scroll to see it all.
For context, this is the modal editor for the Javascript tooltip generator on a deck.gl scatterplot map.

